# How to insert Multiple Query into different tables with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

How to insert Multiple Query into different tables with foreign key?
I have below code, would anyone help me to modified below code!

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO student(fname, lname, phone, email,status) VALUES('".$_POST["fname"]."','".$_POST["lname"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["status"]."')";
        $res = $db_handle->executeQuery($query);
    if(!$res){
            $message="Please try again!.";
    } else {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
}
```

my Tables:
student,
course,
schedule

(`id_schedule`, `id`, `id_courses`, `schedule_year`, `schedule_semester`)
"id" connect to student table.
"id_courses" connect to the id_courses into the courses table!

My DB:

```html
--
-- Table structure for table `courses`
--


--
-- Constraints for table `schedule`
--
ALTER TABLE `schedule`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `schedule_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_courses`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id_courses`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `schedule_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I don't know much about `PHP`, but as a generic principle for most of the programming languages, do not use `parameter substitution` by concatenation, especially against `SQL injection`, rather prefer using `placeholders` for them those are prepared outside of the query string.

Comment: You cannot insert into multiple tables. See LAST_INSERT_ID(), or its equivalent for your API.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.